# Sounds not playing on iPhone 7 iOS 10

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have apps that play sounds. They play fine on an iPad Air 10.3.1, but not on my iPhone 7 10.3.1. I've  tried different audio formats and nothing plays on the iPhone 7. Is there some entry in the plist or some other setting I need to get sounds to play on iPhone 7?

ViewController.h

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSError *err;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"]];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];
    if (err) NSLog(@"error");
    player.volume = 1.0;
    player.delegate = self;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
    NSLog(@"sound should have played");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this and now it works. Not sure why it worked before on other devices.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```